# Bounded operator with an inverse on a dense invariant subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach spaces such that $X$ is continuously embedded in $Y$. We suppose also that $X$ is dense in $Y$. Let $A\, \colon \, Y \to Y$ be a bounded operator that maps $X$ into itself such that the restriction $A_{|X} \colon X \to X$ is a bounded operator.

Do we have: $A_{|X}$ invertible $\implies$ $A$ invertible ?

If $X$ is not supposed to be endowed with a Banach structure, a counter-example is given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The norm of $X$ can be strictly finer than the one of $Y$. The spaces could be something like $X=\ell^2\hookrightarrow c_0=Y$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $\left\lVert\cdot\right\rVert_X$ is indeed strictly stronger than $\left\lVert\cdot\right\rVert_Y$ otherwise $X=Y$ and the question is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice question because everybody should rather immediately think that the answer must be negative (such a theorem would look much too good) -- and nevertheless it is far from obvious (at least for me) how to find a counterexample.

I believe that an example is contained in the paper https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01174563 of K. Dayanithy from 1978: For the finite measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb N$ with $\mu(\{n\})=1/(n!)^2$ he caculates the spectral radii of the operators $T_p$ on $L^p(\mu)$ defined by $(x_n)_n\mapsto (x_{n+1}/(n+1))_n$, namely $r(T_p)=0$ for $p>2$ and $r(T_2)=1$. There is thus an element $\lambda$ of the spectrum of $T_2$ with $|\lambda|=1$. Since the spectrum of $T_p$ for $p>0$ is $\{0\}$ we thus get for every $p>2$ that $A= \lambda -T_2$ is not invertible on $L^2(\mu)$ but its restriction to $L^p(\mu)$ is invertible.

Note finally that $L^p(\mu)$ is contained in $L^2(\mu)$ because the measure is finite and it is dense because even the space of finite sequences (i.e., with only finitely many non-zero coordinates) is dense.

---

I would like very much to see a simpler example!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think you just made a typo: $(x_n)_n \mapsto (x_{n+1}/(n+1))_n$

Comment: You are right, of course. I have edited the answer.